# nested grep pattern search from same input file and create multiple output files

Tags: awk, sed, grep

I have two grep patterns

first do pattern1 - (search for main chapters)

```
grep -rwA 2 [E:Chapter] input.txt > output.txt
```

then check for pattern2 (search for sub chapters), `if pattern2 exists`

```
grep -rwA 8 Sub\sChapter input.txt > chapter1.txt

else go to next match for pattern1
```

sample input file:

```
bla bla E:chapter1
bla bla bla bla bla
bla bla bla bla bla
Sub Chapter bla bla bla
bla bla bla
Sub chapter bla bla bla
bla....
bla bla E:chapter2
bla bla bla bla bla
Sub Chapter bla bla bla
bla bla bla
Sub chapter bla bla bla
bla....
```

I'm trying to parse a large text with many chapters and some containing sub chapters in it.. I want to create individual output files for chapter containing sub-chapters that are named chapter1.txt , chapter2.txt, etc.. to be created, then I want to dump about 8 lines of each sub chapter under their respective chapter files.. like using grep -rwA 8..

how do i do this? Awk and while loop ?

Expected outputs

> Chapter1.txt

```
Sub Chapter1
bla bla bla
...about 8 lines here.
Sub Chapter2
...
Sub Chapter3
...
```

> Chapter2.txt

```
Sub Chapter1
...
Sub Chapter2
...
```

Comment: To be more complete, please include the expected output from your sample input  thx

Comment: edited to describe sample output files

Answer (score 0):

`awk` to the rescue!

since your sample input will be not differentiate for `-A8` option, I used `-A1` equivalent.

```
$ awk -v a=1 '/E:chapter/   {ch++; c=a+1} 
              /Sub Chapter/ {c=a+1} 
              c&&c--        {print > "Chapter"ch}' file
```

will give

```
==> Chapter1 <==
bla bla E:chapter1
bla bla bla bla bla
Sub Chapter bla bla bla
bla bla bla

==> Chapter2 <==
bla bla E:chapter2
bla bla bla bla bla
Sub Chapter bla bla bla
bla bla bla
```

**UPDATE**
to add headers

```
$ awk -v a=1 '/E:chapter/   {file="Chapter"++ch".txt"; 
                             print "Chapter"ch > file; 
                             sc=0; c=a+1} 
              /Sub Chapter/ {c=a+1; 
                             print "Sub Chapter"++sc > file} 
              c&&c--        {print > file}' file


==> Chapter1.txt <==
Chapter1
bla bla E:chapter1
bla bla bla bla bla
Sub Chapter1
Sub Chapter bla bla bla
bla bla bla

==> Chapter2.txt <==
Chapter2
bla bla E:chapter2
bla bla bla bla bla
Sub Chapter1
Sub Chapter bla bla bla
bla bla bla
```

if you want to skip the actual lines where Chapter and Sub Chapter lines exist, add `; next` at the end of each block.

Comment: Can you please explain what this does: {ch++; c=a+1}

Comment: `ch++` increment chapter count and `c=a+1` sets the count for number of lines to be printed (1+ *after* value)

Answer (score 0):

Your question isn't clear but it sounds like all you need is:

```
awk '/E:chapter/{close(out); out="chapter"++c} {print > out}' input.txt
```

If that's not what you need then edit your question to include concise, testable sample input and expected output. Right now you're kinda describing your input and output but there's nothing there we could run a test against to prove if our script produces the posted expected output from the posted sample input.